# Performance: While-loop

Tags: c#, performance, loops, while-loop, il

Simple question:
What is best, method 1 or method 2?

Is method 2 faster/better:

```
List<int> data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).ToList();
int j = 0;

// Method 1
while (j < data.Count)
{
    // do something
    j++;
}

j = 0;

// Method 2   
while (j++ < data.Count)
{
    // do something
}
```

or would a simple for-loop still be better?

**Update:**
according to the comments, a subquestion:
Should while-loops be avoided or should for-loops be avoided and replaced with these while-loops?

Comment: I do have a feeling, that after jitting & optimization theese two methods will be compiled into the same machine code

Comment: Isn't there slight logical difference?

Comment: There IS a difference, but only that `j` in method 2 will be always 1 ahead of `j` in method 2, considering the amount of iterations, when inside the while body.

Comment: @Peter the only *functional* difference is if `j` is used inside the loop. The other differences; really minimal./

Comment: Frankly, this is actually a `for` loop or `foreach` loop, and should be written as such, or even better: a `foreach` loop over `Enumerable.Range(...)` ***without*** calling `ToList()`

Comment: updated the question. so should for-loops be used or just method 1?

Comment: Strange that this has downvotes but I still get different answers from people.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, use a for loop over an array. The JIT compiler has special range-check-elimination optimizations for that. It will matter more than little things such as where the increment goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest neither, rather I would suggest this

```
List<int> data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).ToList();
int j = -1;



// Method 1   

while (++j < data.Count)
{
    // do something
}

int j = 0;
do
    {
        //anything
    } while (++j<data.count);
```

pre-increment operation is faster than post, although a small performance advantage

Comment: Is the "++i is faster than i++" argument still valid? I thought I read somewhere that it wasn't anymore (or I could be wrong???)?

Comment: @user1107474 I would love to see where you found that.

Comment: @juFo I just did a quick search on stackoverflow and the answer could be language-dependent. I may have seen a post referring to a different language.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference (at least significative in terms of performance, you should measure on **really** heavy calculations)

I would choose the first one, cause it seems clearer, **to me**.

Answer (score -1):

Both are take same execution time,There is no difference.You can use any of that in your poject.